# Getting rid of a line with a perfect match (not substring) using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to delete a line which matches the word `name` but doesn't delete the lines have something following it. I can't seem to find an answer to this. I know `sed -i '/name/d' *` would delete the whole line matching the word `name` but this is not what I want. 
An example will clarify my question.
If input is -

```
 name xav
 name lmn
 name
 name abc
```

Then the output should be -

```
 name xav
 name lmn
 name abc
```

basically the line with `name` and  **nothing else**  should be deleted. The rest need to stay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anchor the text in the regex

```
sed -i '/^name$/d'
```

Comment: This is correct, but can you make a slight modification and tell me how to integrate it if there is a single space ` ` before `name`? Thanks!

Comment: Before `name`?  You can have spaces in the regexp, and also a `?` after to make it optional.

Comment: @Henrik Can you write the command please? Just before name there's a blank space

Comment: `sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*name[[:blank:]]*$/d'`.  That will delete lines containing **only** `name` and any number (zero-or-more) of leading or trailing spaces or tabs.